# Different probabilities for source-ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

I have three sources in my model each having different agent. Is there a way I can set the probability of input rate to be 30:20:50. Which mean if I set the input rate to  be 1 per minute the probability that it should be from source1 is 30%, from source2 is 20%, from source3 is 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Simply create a parameter with the overall rate (1/min), name it `p_TotalRate`

In your sources, do not write a number but a formula matching your criteria, i.e. in Source1 `p_TotalRate * 0.3`

Alternatively, write more advanced setup code in a function (returning a double) and call that function in your Source arrival rate.